# VBScript with Permissions to Certain Groups

Tags: windows-xp, permissions, script

In the root there’s a folder called “med” inside that folder there’s a folder called “Medprogs” and inside that folder there’s a file called “Ansi.key”

C:\Med\Medprogs\Ansi.key

I need the “Medprogs” folder to have write permissions and the “Ansi.Key” to have Modify permissions. Both to the  “Everyone” Group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a [decent description and example vbs](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/825751) using [xcacls](http://ss64.com/nt/xcacls.html) to do this.